# how to copy a string into a part of another string in swift?

Tags: ios, string, swift

For example:

```
let test = "hello"
let second_string = "world"
```

I have a string called `test`, it contains 5 characters.
Then I have another string: `var result:String`
I want the first 3 characters in `result` will be the first 3 characters in `test` and its rest part will be the content in `second_string`.
Like

```
result[0...2] = test[0...2]
result[3...7] = second_string[0...4]
//just pseudo  code
```

This is my `extension code`:

```
extension String {
var length: Int {
    return self.characters.count
}
subscript (i:Int) -> Character{
    return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
}
subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return String(self[i] as Character)
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    return substringWithRange(Range(start: startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex), end: startIndex.advancedBy(r.endIndex)))
}
}
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let test = "hello"
let second_string = "world"
let range = test.startIndex.advancedBy(0)..<test.startIndex.advancedBy(3)
print(test[range] + second_string)
```